# How do you query only part of the data in the row of a column - Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column called `NAME`, I have 2000 rows in that column that are filled with people's full names, e.g. `ANN SMITH`. How do I do a query that will list all the people whose first name is `ANN`? There are about 20 different names whose first name is `ANN` but the surname is different.

I tried

```
and (NAME = 'ANN')
```

but it returned zero results.

I have to enter the FULL name and (NAME = 'ANN SMITH') ANN SMITH to even get a result .

I just want to list all the people with there first name as ANN

Comment: Why don't you put first and last names in different columns?

Comment: Well, I hope you have at least the Name and Surname in order (meaning Name first followed by a space and then Surname for every record), but if you have this requirement then there is a design fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in your where clause:

```
Where Name like 'ANN %'
```

Should work mate.

ANN% will find all results where ANN is first then anything after.

%ANN% will find the 3 letters ANN in any part of that rows field.

Hope it helps

Also usually Name is separated into First names and second name columns. 
this will save Having to use wild cards in your SQL and provide A bit more normalized data.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NAME
FROM NAMES
WHERE NAME LIKE 'ANN %'
```

This should wildcard select anything that begins with 'ANN' followed by a space.